# Analytics tool recommendation for an on-premise web app

Tags: google-analytics, mixpanel

We're developing a new web app that is installed on-premise on the customer's network. Is there a way to still track their usage and report back to an analytic tool like Mixpanel or Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an air-gapped scenario, where the app has no connectivity to the outside world? If that's not the case, you can still use standard telemetry tools with an on-prem solution. Our on-prem service uses Segment, although customers have the ability to turn it off if they so choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **Google Analytics** with **Measurement Protocol**: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1

The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make HTTP requests to **send raw user interaction data directly to Google Analytics servers**. This allows developers to measure how users interact with their business from almost any environment.